# Impaired verbal communication, but normal reading and writing skills?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, communication, language-processing, speech, speech-comprehension

Is there any cognitive disability or disfunction that impairs both speech production and listening comprehension, while reading and writing skills are at a normal level or better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a reminder that Stack Exchange is not an appropriate place to get a diagnosis; a vague description of symptoms may indicate a variety of possible outcomes.  See a doctor instead.  That said:

One general term for disorders that affect some language modalities and not others, when the cause is psychological rather than physical (ie, not deafness, muscle weakness, paralysis, etc), is [aphasia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphasia):

> To be diagnosed with aphasia, a person's speech or language must be
>   significantly impaired in one (or several) of the four communication
>   modalities following acquired brain injury or have significant decline
>   over a short time period (progressive aphasia). The four communication
>   modalities are auditory comprehension, verbal expression, reading and
>   writing, and functional communication.

Aphasia is most commonly associated with stroke or dementia, and several [sub-types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphasia#Classification) involve both speech production and verbal comprehension difficulties, while not necessarily affecting reading or writing abilities.

Other diagnoses are also possible, as [language disorders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_disorder) may consist of a combination of a variety of possible aspects of language ability, while not affecting others.  For example, children with both receptive (comprehension) and expressive (speech) delays may be diagnosed with [specific language impairment (SLI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_language_impairment):

> ... diagnosed when a child's language does not develop normally and
>   the difficulties cannot be accounted for by generally slow
>   development, physical abnormality of the speech apparatus, autism
>   spectrum disorder, apraxia, acquired brain damage or hearing loss.

Though relatively rarely, it is possible for literacy to be largely unaffected by SLI.

Additionally, [comorbidity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comorbidity) is also possible, such as a combination of speech [agnosia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auditory_verbal_agnosia) and [apraxia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apraxia_of_speech), and if other symptoms are present, then yet other diagnoses would apply, such as [autism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autism_spectrum), where again, it is possible for some language skills (such as verbal communication) to be impaired while others (such as literacy) are largely unaffected.

For a general overview of the field, see [speech and language impairment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_and_language_impairment) and [communication disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_disorder).  A summary of technical terminology used to classify symptoms can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_language_disorders).